# Exporting to latex an expression: it doesn't appear the same as in mathematica

Tags: export, latex

Mathematica doesn't export in latex the same way it is written within the software.

Consider the following expression:

```
(1/(16 Ω))γ ((1+2 nEnv) Cos[β]^2 (6 θ+Sin[2 θ])+4 Cos[β] Sin[θ] (-2+(1+2 nEnv) Sin[β] Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ])+Sin[β] (4 (1+2 nEnv) θ Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[β]+Sin[ϕ] (-16 Sin[θ/2]^2-(1+2 nEnv) Sin[β] (-6 θ+Sin[2 θ]) Sin[ϕ])))
```

Which has this shape on mathematica:

[image]

If I right click, copy as Latex, it returns me:

$$\frac{\gamma  \left(\sin (\beta ) \left(\sin (\phi ) \left(-16 \sin ^2\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)-(2 \text{nEnv}+1) \sin (\beta ) (\sin (2 \theta )-6 \theta ) \sin (\phi )\right)+4 \theta  (2 \text{nEnv}+1) \sin (\beta ) \cos ^2(\phi )\right)+4 \cos (\beta ) \sin (\theta ) ((2 \text{nEnv}+1) \sin (\beta ) \sin (\theta ) \sin (\phi )-2)+(2 \text{nEnv}+1) \cos ^2(\beta ) (6 \theta +\sin (2 \theta ))\right)}{16 \Omega }+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{\Omega }\right)^2\right)$$

As you can see even though the expression is the same the text is not formatted in the same way: the fraction takes the full place for instance.

How to fix it to have the exact way it renders in mathematica ?

Comment: Actually Mathematica is not using LaTeX internally for rendering. These are two very different design principles, and it is hopeless to mimic one with another. You mentioned fraction, but what about brackets, what about the position of 2 to denote the square of a function (before or after parenthesis), space between a function and its parenthesis? If you really want to have a closer look export to pdf and insert as a picture.

Comment: @yarchik ok so I cannot have a perfect mathematica to latex translation. About your remark however I am not sure to agree that it would not be possible in principle. In my example it is pretty clear that there is no "in principle" constraint why the order of the term appearing in the equation should change between mathematica and latex. It would be easy to implement in my opinion. Probably that for some "tricky" typo the translation would not be perfect but it can be far better than what it is currently

Comment: You are right, there is a lot of room for improvement.